# Modal Pop Up in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, bootstrap-modal

I want to open modal window when user click create new link.

Mvc automatically generates create view in default but it open in another page. I want it to load in Bootstrap pop-up

Comment: You should have posted at least minimum code that you have tried.

Comment: I'm new to mvc. I tried so many codes.i deleted those codes. i need statrt scratch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please Use below example.

Button/Link, Here I am take button

```
  <button type="button" name="btnLink" id="btnLink">Open Pop</button>
```

Model Pop : put ending of the page

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalPopUp" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog err-pop" style="">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button id="DivClose" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="text-align:center;">
            Put Your Html Element Here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-2+LznWeWgL7AJ1ciaIG5rFP7GKemzzl+K75tRyTByOE="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $("#btnLink").click(function () {
        $('#ModalPopUp').modal('show');
    })
</script>
```

Comment: @Salman if you have any issue ask me.

Comment: Azhar it is working. thank you. but i want default create view inside the that pop up can you help for that. from index page to call add new page inside that pop up

Comment: please share create page code

Comment: Azhar thank you for support. i did it my self. now it's working

Comment: i need help content load to modal but when i click save it not saving.

Comment: you need to add post method

Comment: @Azahr Post Method in form tag?

Comment: yes, and in controller [httpPost] Methode name

Comment: An external link?

Comment: @ARLibertarian  which external link?